# Laravel Form - Sent as an email in a table

Tags: laravel

I have a form on my website, which has required fields, and non required fields. The user fills in there details and submits the form. This is then emailed to the owner, and the data is then presented in a table.

However is it possible to show only the data that has been filled in and then remove the fields where no data was entered.

So far I have:

Blade Template:

```
div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p><b>First Names</b></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p>{{ $first_names }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Which is then sent and is outputted as a table below:

```
<?php
  if (!empty($titles)) {?>
    <td class="tg-031e">Title:</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">{{ $titles }}</td>
<?php }
?>
```

But I am assuming an else or else if statement would be required. So how would I have it so that only the fields that where filled in where shown in the table please.

Thanks

Comment: do you use balde templates?

Comment: Yes I have a blade template

div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <p><b>First Names</b></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <p>{{ $first_names }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

This is the blade template that is used for the site. The table data example above is used for the email.

Comment: In my above code I have the php tags. Are they still needed?

Comment: not needed. Remove all that and paste the code I wrote in my answer below. Blade templates @if replaces the php tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return nothing when there is no title the code below shoud make it work.

```
@if (isset($titles)) 
    <td class="tg-031e">Title:</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">{{ $titles }}</td>
@endif
```

Let me know if this worls :)

ps: `@if(isset($titles))` does not work try `@if($titles == NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this:

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates#other-blade-control-structures

> Sometimes you may wish to echo a variable, but you aren't sure if the variable has been set. Basically, you want to do this:

```
{{{ isset($name) ? $name : 'Default' }}}
```

> However, instead of writing a ternary statement, Blade allows you to use the following convenient short-cut:

```
{{{ $name or 'Default' }}}
```